# Непреднамеренное закрытие окна программы при вызове функции в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qpushbutton

Начал я изучать *PyQt5* недавно. 
Добравшись до `QPushButton`, я начал экспериментировать с командами, которые выполняются после нажатия кнопки.

Я создал функцию, выводящую в консоль некий текст из списка. Причём, при повторном нажатии выводится следующий элемент списка.

```
jk=['Двач', 'Бред']
x=0
def function():
    if x==0 or x==1:
        print(jk[x])
        x+=1
    else:
        pass
```

Далее создал кнопку, законнектил функцию с кнопкой.

```
button = QPushButton(parent=w, text ='BUTTON')
button.clicked.connect(function)
```

Запустил код, нажал на кнопку, окно зависло и закрылось.

В консоли не появились ошибки и какой-либо другой текст. Поэкспериментировав далее, я понял, что дело в `x+=1`. Убрав эту команду, программа работала как надо, только, конечно же, при повторном нажатии не выводился второй элемент списка.

Вот весь код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
import sys
    
app = QApplication([])
w = QWidget()
w.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 200)
    
jk=['Двач', 'Бред'] 
x=0 
def function():
    if x==0 or x==1:
        print(jk[x])
        x+=1
    else:
        pass
    
app.setStyle('Macintosh')

button = QPushButton(parent=w, text ='BUTTON')
button.clicked.connect(function)
button.move(250, 250)
button.resize(button.sizeHint())

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

У меня встал вопрос - как эта строка кода влияет на выполнение функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить реальную ошибку - всегда запускайте свое приложение в CMD/консоле/терминале.

У вас ошибка:

> if x==0 or x==1:
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

С учетом ООП ваша задача выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, \
    QGridLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.jk = ['Двач', 'Бред'] 
        self.x = 0 
        
        button = QPushButton('BUTTON')
        button.clicked.connect(self.function)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(button)   

    def function(self):
        if self.x == 0 or self.x == 1:
            print(self.jk[self.x])
            self.x += 1
        else:
            pass
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спросите если что-то не понятно.

Comment: Спасибо, проверил в консоли - всё сходится. Но почему тогда после ошибки окно закрывается?